# xls to hashmap in Android

Tags: android

Is there any way to convert my xls table with two columns to hashmap? 
More specifically, I have a table with country names and column with country code and I need to determine the country of origin from phone number. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Please read the FAQs on good questions for SO.  You will get a better response if you show some research and ask specific questions rather than broad abstract ones.  It is, of course possible to read an XLS and do whatever you want with the data therein but there are too many unknowns to give a reasoned answer (e.g. what version of XLS.  One time conversion or at runtime?  file is modified often? stored locally?)  I could on but you get the idea.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this api :

http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html

And you can get data any object what you want.